# Silverlight Datagrid Group by Select Values

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Lets say I have the following values that I'm loading into a datagrid

```
ID  |  Desc
------------------------ 
32     Red Cat
33     Blue Dog
34     Red Dog
37     Green Zebra
42     Reddish Snake
47     Greenlike Gorilla
```

I want to group my values on my data grid by the beginning colour specified in description. So it'll be like this

```
ID  |  Desc
----------------------------
Red:
 32     Red Cat
 34     Red Dog
 42     Reddish Snake
Blue:
 33     Blue Dog
Green:
 37     Green Zebra
 47     Greenlike Gorilla
```

I have this for my code behind :

```
PagedCollectionView pageView = new PagedCollectionView(IEnumerable<MyClass> main);
pageView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("")); //?????
this.MyGrid.ItemsSource = pageView;
```

How would I specify the grouping parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can provide an `IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597591.aspx) to the GroupDescription.  So use :

```
new PropertyGroupDescription("Color", new StringToColorConverter())
```

where **StringToColorConverter** converts the **Desc** property to the color string:

```
public class StringToColorConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((string)value == null) return null;
        return ((string)value).Split(new [] { ' ' }).FirstOrDefault();    
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

*Alternate approach*

If you're able to modify the class, then you could add a simple derived property `Color`.

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Color
    {
        get
        {
            return Desc.Split(new [] { ' ' }).FirstOrDefault();    
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can group on it.

```
new PropertyGroupDescription("Color")
```

Comment: The alternative approach where I made my own class worked great. Thanks. I tried the first method but was not sure how to access the "Desc" column in my datasource

Answer (score 0):

PropertyGroupDescription is just one implementation of [GroupDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.groupdescription%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). You can roll your own. In fact, we can roll one for general purposes:

```
public class LambdaGroupDescription<T> : GroupDescription
{
    public Func<T, object> GroupDelegate { get; set; }

    public LambdaGroupDescription(Func<T, object> groupDelegate)
    {
        this.GroupDelegate = groupDelegate;
    }

    public override object GroupNameFromItem(object item, int level, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return this.GroupDelegate((T)item);
    }
}
```

And then add it to the PagedCollectionView:

```
var pageView = new PagedCollectionView(items);
        pageView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new LambdaGroupDescription<ViewModel>(
            vm => vm.Description.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault()    
        ));
        this.DataGrid.ItemsSource = pageView;
```

**EDIT**

It seems your grouping logic is a little bit more complex than a simple split. You could try something like:

```
public string FormatColor(string color)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(color)) return null;

        if (color.ToUpperInvariant().StartsWith("RED"))
            return "Red";

        if (color.ToUpperInvariant().StartsWith("GREEN"))
            return "Green";

        return color;
    }
```

And then:

```
pageView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new LambdaGroupDescription<ViewModel>(
            vm => FormatColor(vm.Description.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault() as string)
        ));
```

In the FormatColor method you also could use a Dictionary to map "strange" color values to known ones:

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> ColorMap = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
        {"Greenlike", "Green"},
        {"Reddish", "Red"},
    };

public string FormatColor(string color)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(color)) return null;

        if (ColorMap.ContainsKey(color))
            return ColorMap[color];

        return color;
    }
```